# Achievements box missed out on upvotes while reputation tab is correct?

Tags: bug

1st seen on Monday, Nov. 27th: I get 11 UV on this [answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/best-way-to-tell-colleague-that-chat-is-not-a-channel-for-direct-response/7271#7271). But the *top menu > achievements* shows +100 (10*10). I go to the *profile > tabs > activity > [my profile](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/455/oldpadawan?tab=topactivity)* and the *reputation / tab* doesn't match the *menu / achievements*.

This is not about asking for the 10 points, of course, I couldn't care less. Just wonder if someone has seen this before or faced the same issue.

This happens on PC (tested with Firefox / Opera / Edge) or cellphone (iPhone) or digital tablet (Android). Note that the "*Nice Answer*" badge was awarded **before** the +100 points (I had seen it, and it triggered me, so I started to search around).

Searching meta has not been fruitful nor successful. Many related, but linked to posts where deleted items are involved, and the total involves *many* posts.

See this screenshot: +100 in achievements / +110 in reputation tab (total +120 is accurate when looking at the question though) [image: screenshot]

Comment: You might want to just watch the existing [meta.stackexchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303760/wrong-reputation-calculation) but yeah, it happened to me yesterday as well.... Just call it 'surprise rep' :P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem on more sites, not just ours. There's already a post on meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303760/wrong-reputation-calculation

Comment: Ok, got it better reading the post timeline: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/7271/timeline (may worth adding a capture to the question)

Comment: hm... I might not be clear enough on that one, or I'm all messed and don't get it... *achievements box* shows +110 (and that's what I really got in rep change) -> seems accurate. *Reputation tab* shows +120 (110 + 10) -> seems wrong and should show +110. *Timeline* shows +120 (110 + 10) -> seems wrong too. **IF** it's a bug (in the system), it seems different from what I've found on SE so far. Bad wording in my Q or bug in my brain? ^^

Comment: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/455/oldpadawan?tab=reputation <- Maybe the first upvote date being before 12:00  may have play a role in the achievement dropdown glitch

Comment: So you're actually missing 10 rep point in your overall reputation now? Weird, because I noticed the same thing yesterday (box and tab not matching)... but I only noticed because my rep got over 9700 and I didn't get a notification....

Comment: @Tinkeringbell : yep, and that's why I found it weird/bug-ish. I know there had been many issues for long now (tab/box), but never heard of one like that, where the number shown (12 / 110 + 10) exceed the rep gained (110 / 100 + 10).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how this is a different bug than the one that Tinkeringbell [linked you to on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303760/wrong-reputation-calculation-in-achievements-dialog).

Your top bar missed out on one upvote that you got during the hour or two that the reputation changes weren't being sent to the top bar... so it says +100 instead of +110. I'm guessing it's the upvote at 18:23 that's missing as that coincides with the time frame of my missing top bar upvotes.

The +120 is for that question in total, not for a specific date, so it's the **actual** 110 from yesterday along with an additional +10 from today.

The end result is the same - it's *only* a top bar reporting bug. Your actual reputation is unaffected.